# Next largest representable number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ieee-754

ECMA-262 (13th ed.) §6.1.6.1 states that the values of a JS Number are those of a 64-bit float as defined in IEEE-754-2019. Does any major JS vendor provide a method (or a simple combination of methods) to find the smallest representable floating-point number greater than the target? (A C++ analog would be `std::nextafter`).

Comment: What do you count as "major JS vendor"? But the answer still appears to be "no".

Comment: A major web browser or a major JS runtime? I don't know how I can define it further, except through brute enumeration. Whatever the opposite is of "this one guy's obscure Github project."

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75844643/next-largest-representable-number-in-javascript#comment133783218_75844643) @aas Explicit enumeration provides clear scope — which helps make a question clear.

Comment: If no vendor offers this functionality, narrowing down the list of vendors will not reveal one that does.

Comment: @aas In that case, you're looking for the JavaScript runtimes that are using the JVM (e.g. rhino, nashorn, graaljs etc) and have access to `java.lang.Math.nextAfter`. They aren't exactly mainstream (used in browsers or nodejs), but are not obscure one-person projects either.

Comment: If the mostly moribund JVM-based runtimes are the best available, I consider this question answered.